# Getting a notification that a volume has mounted on iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui

An external drive / volume can be connected to an iPad. I want to be able to take an action in my app when this happens and my app is in the foreground - say for example bringing up an import dialog.

On macOS I can write the following to get a notification that a volume has mounted and take an action - here in this basic example I set a property to true:

```swift
struct SomeViewOfMine: View {
   @State private var importDialogVisible = false
   private var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
   init() {
      NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.publisher(for: NSWorkspace.didMountNotification)
         .sink { _ in 
            self.importDialogVisible = true
      }
      .store(in: &cancellable)
   }

   // Other code in my view here
}
```

But I can't find the same functionality within iOS. Am I missing something or is there a way to achieve this?